# Display the Group Title after the content in Views Grouped By

Tags: 7, views

I've got a View which displays a grid of content. The nodes are of type Photo Gallery and I'm showing a grid of thumbnails, each thumbnail representing one node. I'm grouping the content by Post Date so it appears like this:

[image]

There are two galleries posted on 09/04/2013, 1 gallery on 09/01 and 3 galleries on 08/28 and this is all well and good. However, my client would like the group title to appear below the content. So it should show `Rome 2` and `Rome 2013` and then below that should show `Post date: 09/04/2013`.

Is there any way I can make the group title render after the content instead of before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the `views-view-grid.tpl.php` for your views. Otherwise, it will be effect all grid layout into your site.

The correct template suggestions for views be `views-view-grid--[views_name].tpl.php` or `views-view-grid--[views_name]--[display_id].tpl.php`.

To know more template suggestions for views, you can follow below step.

- Go to Administration » Structure » Views
- Edit your views
- Open the correct display of the views.
- Click on  information link for theme under Advanced tab.
- A popup be display for all template suggestions for a particular
  views.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it. There is a views template which I could copy into my theme and override. Since I was displaying my content as a Grid, I copied the `views-view-grid.tpl.php` into my theme, changed it, flushed my cache and viola!